# PHP - Symfony - Process terminated immediately after execution

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I am using an application that is proxying connection between server and client for VNC connection.
So, I would like to run this application via Process component of Symfony in PHP.
Laravel Framework is used in this project and trying to run the application by requesting a page(route).

The problem is application needs to run continuously in the background. The output from process run from CMD.exe is  below;

[image: websockify run from CMD.exe]

As a code, I have tried the following combinations;

```
    $process = new Process(['websockify.exe', '7777', '127.0.0.1:5901']);
    $process->start();
    $process->waitUntil(function ($type, $output) {
        echo $output;
        return strpos($output, 'proxying from');
    });
```

The output:
[image: output]

But process is terminated after I got this output. I just want it to be run continuously in the background.

I also tried with `$process->run();` but the requested page keep waiting for the application to be terminated until the timeout. (Process runs successfully but cannot complete the page request)

I tried with exec function (with / without `> /dev/null 2>&1 &`);

```
exec('websockify.exe 7777 127.0.0.1:5901 > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

But still same as the Process component. It terminates the process immediately.
Also tried the following code but no luck.

```
    $process = new Process(['websockify.exe', '7777', '127.0.0.1:5901', '&']);
    $process->disableOutput();
    $process->setTimeout(1800);
    $process->start();
```

As a summary, I would like to run a process that should keep running in background in PHP.

**Environment:** Windows 10 and WAMP Server
**PHP version:** 7.4.0
**Laravel version:** v7.6.1
**Symfony Process version:** v5.0.7

GitHub link for application I used: [websockify](https://github.com/novnc/websockify)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. It runs the application in different thread.

```
$process = Process::fromShellCommandline('wmic process call create "<FilePath>websockify.exe 7777 127.0.0.1:5901"');
$process->start();
```

Now the output is:

[image: output]

I can use the "ProcessId" to handle processes such as stopping, checking if it is running.

Only problem is that I cannot get the output from the actual application. If I found a solution for this I will update the answer.

PS: This solution is for Windows.